# Add SFPX Extension to an existing App Package

Tags: spfx, pnp, spfx-extensions, pnp-provision

Just wondered if anyone has successfully added an SPFx extension to an existing App Package or provisioned without using an package.

We have an existing hosted provider application, an associated app package and event handlers to execute custom code on appinstalled and appuninstalling events.

We've written some new SPFx command sets to provide a consistence experience across modern and classic document library experiences. We've deployed the SPFx components to an Azure CDN but we can't find any reference material covering the following scenarios:

1) Adding the SPFx components to an existing app package (none SPFx)
2) Using PnP to programmatically provision the command set

We need a single app package for the office store...

Thoughts and guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Framework solutions are currently not supported in the Office Store and even though it might be technically possible to package them in existing add-in packages, it's not supported at this moment either.

Comment: SPfx solutions now can be published to the store! https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/publish-to-marketplace-overview